# "be the first to see" or "who saw"?

Tags: difference

I stuck with the following sentence and need help to choose the correct one:

> Join me on Facebook to be the first **to see** my new paintings

or

> Join me on Facebook to be the first **who saw** my new paintings

Answer (score 1):

Go for the first one...

> Join me on Facebook to be the first to see my new paintings

The reason is, you are asking someone to join your FB page. It's in the future so whoever joins you *will* be the first *to see* the paintings.

On the other hand, using the past tense means things happened in past. The 'who saw' is okay if you are talking about the event already happened. How can someone who has not joined your page *already saw* your paintings?